# SharePoint Personnel Accountability (Out of Box)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a question and I hope that maybe you guys can help me out. I am sure it is staring me in the face, but... I am trying to come up with a List or possible way for people to come in and (maybe just a Team Lead) put in their Personnel Status for that day, such as Out Sick, In Office, Teleworking, On Vacation, etc... for each of their personnel, by section. There are around 100 personnel, I would say, and about 10 sections.

Right now I have a List for each Section with a Column for each Status (Out Sick, In Office, etc...). Then I have Check Boxes (multiple Selection) for each Status with each individuals Name by it. This way they go to their Section List and select all of the Personnel that are In Office that day, or Out Sick, and so on. Then I roll this up with a List View web part pulling from all of the Section Lists and filtering based on who is Out of the Office (Vacation, Out Sick, Teleworking, etc...). So, this List View is just titled "Out of Office Personnel".

What I would like is a efficient way of inputting this data per section and then rolling it up to a Report of some sort that could tell me a status or even who hasn't inputted their daily accountability. Anyone?

Comment: If I understood your question well, you should be able to make a simple option list and a button with a question like "out of the office ? update your status here !". people doing this will accordingly to the account they use on the site update the corresponding section status. you can easily do such a trick with a incorporated code snippet. if you confirm it, i'm going to post a more detailed answer

Comment: Yeah. I need everyone to be able to enter their Status Daily even if they are in the Office or Out. Also need to separate them or, at least, be able to distinguish them by which Team/Section they are in.

Comment: Maybe make a second List for lookup that would contain the Name, Section they are in, etc... ?

Comment: Do you know that you can add custom fields to list ? Do you manage your authentication via an Active Directory ?

Comment: Yes. So let me explain my dilemma a little more. So, all the info that we really need is (column) Name, Team, Location, Status. Easy enough. So if I make a List with those Columns then every day 90+ people would go there and enter their info and there'd be 90 entries.... then tomorrow 90 more, then 90 more... it'll get HUGE, real fast. If I make it 1 entry per person and they just update it every day then it'll overwrite yesterdays and I have no Log if I want to see who was Out last week. So I am trying to figure out a way to get all of this info in a list, or a few lists and roll it up.

Comment: Yes. Active Directory (but I don't have access to it, unfortunately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I've fully understood your issue I'll try to summarize the options that I know and I would recommend :

- You can create a single List, and everyday, you erase all data older than 1 or 2 weeks into this list (you can easily automate erasing server side with a scheduled task or a sharepoint job). considering your 90 entries per days, it should not be more than 1000 entries depending on the working days of your company. A list with 1000 entries still have a correct size to manage. Then you can filter what you want in the same view, it's the "simple" way.
- You can either (if you got much time to spent) create a custom database with a user table, and use the instance of SP to access it. I've never done such a thing but I know it's a possiblity. Thus you have to code a bit of an UI and then do a secure query to your database, to store the daily status of the users. Maybe it's a bit of an overkill to create a database only to store one table.
- I can think of a third thing, but seems to be 'dirty'. each user could a have a json file stored into a document library onto your SP, and via a simple JS/HTML formulary, you could add each day a status into user's JSON file by storing for example this way :

  *{ user : { id/name : "example" { { status : "sick", date : "06-02-2015" }, { status : "office", date : "06-03-2015" } }, ... }}*

Then you could do a little back office, which could read the data's your interested with. It's globally the same way to go as the database one, but less complicated and less time wasting.

Do not hesitate to ask me for any precision on one point if youre not sure of something.

Comment: I like the simplest solution that you mentioned. 2 questions: Is there a way of possibly storing those List entries older than, say, 1 or 2 days onto my desktop or into a different list as maybe an Excel tracking log or something? Second question is about making a Lookup Column based on Team, so if they select their Team as Program Support, then it'll give them an option to select their name from a list of Personnel in the Program Support Team... as opposed to typing in their Last Name, First Name every time. Playing with Lookup Columns now.

Comment: Why not automatically retrieve their names with the SharePoint current context ? You can easily take the column Author as the one to associate name with status, they will then not have to type their names. And about the list extract, I know that you can extract to an Excel file, but I don't know if you can select a specific content to extract from.

Comment: Plus, based on the Author column, it will prevent identity theft when writting their names.

Comment: Awesome idea. But a lot of times it would be the Team Leads entering their personnel status, not each individual.

Comment: So, what I did was Made a List of all Personnel with Columns; Full Name, Location, Team, Job Title.

Then I hand jammed, unfortunately, everyone's Names and info into there (but I figure I can use this later as well as a database for other Lists).

Comment: Then I created the Daily Accountability List and took out the default Title Column and added a Name Column (lookup column reaching to the Personnel List and pulling in the Full Name as well as the Location and Team) and a Status Column (Drop Down with Status options like In Office, Out Sick, Vacation, Late Arrival, etc...). Now all they do is go there and Add Item and all they see are 2 options in the Form, one drop down with all of the Names (Alphabetically) and another drop down with their Status. They select their Name and Status and it automatically pulls in their Location and Team as well

Comment: I have it Grouped by Location and Team. I also have different views setwhere the Default View only shows where Created is = [Today]. So that's Today's Statuses. Then a Yesterday's Status View, a Past Statuses View (Grouped by Date Created)
So now I just need to figure out a Retention Policy and delete them after so long. Gotta get with the big dogs and see how far back they want to keep Statuses. At some point they just need to let Deltek keep track of that. Lol I am hoping no longer than 1 month Retention, this way the List stays manageable
Anything you guys think I am missing or any input?

Comment: You've done a good job, but you will not be able to control if the user has entered his own name. you will have hard time maintaining your "database" list if a new employee is hired or other moving, etc ... but you don't have the control over the Active Directory so it's hard to play with LDAP to retrieve automatically such informations. Finally, I hope  for you users will take 30 seconds per day to fill these informations (it's a constant war !)

Comment: Hahaha. I feel you! That is the key... actually getting people to use it! The thing that REALLY irritates me is that we are using 2010 Standard! I soooo with we had Enterprise! We are going to be moving to 2013 Enterprise here in a few months and that is gonna be a Game Changer! I can't wait to use Excel Services finally!!! Lol. We have a pretty good OnBoarding process in place, so I will just need to maintain some sort of Checklist for when new personnel arrives as far as putting them in the database and adding them to the proper Permissions Groups, but shouldn't be difficult. Thanks so much!